# How to query embedded object field with sql from hazelcast?

Tags: java, sql, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to get complex java object from hazelcast using sql approach.

My data object contains embedded object like

```java
Person{
    ...
    HumanName name;
    ...
}
HumanName {
    String firstName;
}
```

And I'm trying to get this `firstName` field using sql.

```java
SqlResult result = hz.getSql().execute("SELECT p.id, p.name.firstName FROM Patient as p ");
```

It says "Column 'name.firstName' not found in table p"

I know it is possible to reach with predicates, like

```java
patientIMap.values( Predicates.equal( "name.firstName", "John" ));
```

But predicates seems to be not applicable in my case, as I also need to perform Map joins, and it seems to be impossible with predicates.

I also added following mapping:

```java
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig = new ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig();


clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass("com.example.model.Patient");
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass("com.example.model.HumanName");
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);
clientConfig.setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig);


SerializationConfig serializationConfig = clientConfig.getSerializationConfig().setEnableSharedObject(true);
clientConfig.setSerializationConfig(serializationConfig);
var hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

hz.getSql().execute("CREATE MAPPING \"Patient\" EXTERNAL NAME \"Patient\"\n" +
                "TYPE IMap\n" +
                "OPTIONS (\n" +
                "  'keyFormat' = 'java',\n" +
                "  'keyJavaClass' = 'java.lang.String',\n" +
                "  'valueFormat' = 'java',\n" +
                "  'valueJavaClass' = 'com.example.model.Patient'\n" +
                ")");
```

Comment: Nested field access is not supported in 5.0. We're working right now and hope to release it in Hazelcast 5.1. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/19954

Answer (score 0):

Nested field access is not supported in 5.0.